# matplotlib filenotfounderror site-packages

Tags: python, matplotlib, filenotfounderror

matplotlib has completely broken my python env.

When i run:
`import matplotlib as plt`
I received:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\SamCurtis.AzureAD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib.libs\.load-order-matplotlib-3.7.1'

I receive the same error if i try to pip install OR pip uninstall matplotlib
Infact all my pip functionality is broken (i cannot pip freeze, uninstall / install) anything.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into a similar problem just now after attempting to downgrade back to my old matplotlib version from 3.7.1. pip was throwing up this matplotlib.libs error even when I wasn't trying to do anything involving matplotlib.

The solution was to delete the `matplotlib` *and* `mpl_toolkits` directories from `site-packages`. Then I was able to reinstall my old matplotlib version and use pip as usual.